# Django manage.py runserver graceful reloading

Tags: django, opencv

I am working on a Django project, which integrates a webcam and OpenCV. For the webcam access, I use following code. The webcam can be released if I use `Ctrl + C` to end a running server, but if the server reloads itself after the code change, the webcam can not be released properly and therefore will be not available. How can I detect hot reloading so I can close the webcam properly?

I am aware of the option of forbidding hot reloading but this is rather uncomfortable. Is there any option I can realize programmatically?

```
class VideoCamera(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.video = None

    def __del__(self):
        if self.video is not None and self.video.isOpened():
            self.video.release()

    def get_frame(self):
        try:
            self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
            success, image = self.video.read()
            self.video.release()
            ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)
            return jpeg.tobytes()
        except (SystemExit, KeyboardInterrupt, Exception) as e:
            self.video.release()
            raise e
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29867070/django-how-to-run-a-function-when-server-exits

Answer (score 0):

Few ideas

1) You could connect on the `file_change` signal that is triggered on file change before reload takes place

https://github.com/django/django/blob/9386586f31b8a0bccf59a1bff647cd829d4e79aa/django/utils/autoreload.py#L24

```
def notify_file_changed(self, path):
    results = file_changed.send(sender=self, file_path=path)
    logger.debug('%s notified as changed. Signal results: %s.', path, results)
    if not any(res[1] for res in results):
        trigger_reload(path)
```

2) Simply monkey patch trigger reload function and inject webcam closing code

https://github.com/django/django/blob/9386586f31b8a0bccf59a1bff647cd829d4e79aa/django/utils/autoreload.py#L221

Answer (score 0):

If your class is a singleton, which it appears to be, create an instance of your class in its file and then add Django signal handlers to perform the clean up. As it is generally [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6104568/6783666) to use `__del__`, I would recommend you add a signal (system signals like SIGINT/ctrl+C) handler which forwards it as a Django signal. This means, listen on `file_changed` from `django.utils.autoreload` and `SIGINT`.

To use the singleton in other files, import it with `from my_app.singleton import my_singleton`.

```py
# my_app/singleton.py

class MySingleton:
    def __init__(self):
        """Init code here"""

    def close(self):
        """Shutdown code here"""

my_singleton = MySingleton()
```

Then, register your signal handlers for your app. This is the standard AFAIK.

```py
# my_app/apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig


class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = "my_app"

    def ready(self):
        import my_app.signals
```

The signal handler file itself, import the singleton and close it on shutdown. This is called on file_changed and SIGINT.

```py
# my_app/signals.py
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.utils.autoreload import file_changed
from my_app.signal_definitions import system_shutdown_signal
from my_app.singleton import my_singleton

@receiver(file_changed)
@receiver(system_shutdown_signal)
def my_shutdown_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    my_singleton.close()
```

Register a handler to catch the SIGINT signal from the system.

```py
# my_app/__init__.py
import signal
import sys

from iot.signal_definitions import system_shutdown_signal


def _forward_to_django_shutdown_signal(signal, frame):
    print(f"Shutting down Django {sys.argv}")
    system_shutdown_signal.send("system")
    sys.exit(0)


signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, _forward_to_django_shutdown_signal)
```

The Django signal used to propagate the system SIGINT signal.

```py
# my_app/signal_definitions.py
from django.dispatch import Signal

system_shutdown_signal = Signal()
```