# Django trigger an event on server stopped

Tags: python, django, server

I have a Django server (running on built-in server-container). Want to do something before app shutdown. Is there a way to trigger an event when server (or whole app) stopped/terminated.

Comment: Possible dupe - check out Python's `atexit` and this recipe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29867070/django-how-to-run-a-function-when-server-exits

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django: How to run a function when server exits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29867070/django-how-to-run-a-function-when-server-exits)